# Хочу научиться создавать смартконтракты

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smart-contract, solidity

Я новичок. Знаний языков программирования еще нет.

*Конечная цель - научиться создавать смартконтракты в сети Ethereum и Binance Smart Chain.*

Немного почитав, узнал, что для написания смартконтрактов используется язык программирования Solidity. Так же подсказали, что для начала нужно начать с изучения JavaScript или Python. Аргументировали тем, что Solidity написан на их основе.

Прошу совета, кто изучает или уже изучил эту тему. С чего правильно начать? Какой материал можете посоветовать?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: с базового курса информатики, поток с базового курса программирования и т.д.

Comment: Сам Solidity никакого отношения к JavaScript и Python не имеет, но один из этих языков Вам понадобится для публикации и взаимодействия со смарт-контрактом. Ну или IDE вроде Тruffle.
Ну и недурно научится разворачивать собственную приватную Ethereum-сеть - точно пригодится.
И конечно - то, что написал Михаил выше.

Comment: нужно базовое понимание о том, как работает блокчейн, и все.
Если будет сложно, тогда основы информацики и немного другого языка программирования не помешает.